# iOS. Webview with embeded youtube and vimeo player playing at background

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiwebview, youtube, vimeo

I have a problem with webview. Once webview is released, the embedded player(vimeo or youtube) continues playing in background (if video is playing at the same time) and embedded player sometimes disappears. How can I fix this?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
-(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [YourWebView loadHTMLString:nil baseURL:nil];
}
```